# BrowserContent unable to render my page and redirects. What should I do?

Tags: browser, blackberry

When I log in, instead of showing the homepage, it redirects back to log in page, on valid user name and password. It only happens with BrowserContent, and not in BrowserField or any where else. What could be the problem?

[This is to be noted that I am using the sample provided in the 4.5 JDE]
More information: I have tried the page for authentication, like what happens when I input wrong user name and password, the validation is done perfectly...

I track the result of the input-stream for each of the URL, and to know why the redirection is happening.. I found that an HTML is inserted above the page's normal HTML, that shows hyperlink that an object is moved to the log in page, and the main page is not viewed at all.

More information: I have also tracked whether the set-cookie is maintained or not.. The session is maintained...

There is one more bug.. The browserContent keeps on redirecting to the page requested, and on fail of load, it gives RenderingException stating that maximum attempts of redirection fail. In case there is a referrer, it redirects the page to it. In the attachment, I have removed the link name for security.